# Google Chrome Driver Selenium

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, curl, selenium-chromedriver

`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://google.com`

This command working for google.com from docker selenium container , but not working for specific public websites. It`s possible to send CURL from the same container , but chrome request is not working

I want to get result after send request from container with

`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://google.com`

command , it`s working for google.com but not working on other  some public websites

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to get a result from the container with the given command. The command is not designed to work with non-Google websites. You will need to use other tools to make the request and get the response.

You can use cURL, wget, Selenium WebDriver, or another tool to make the request from the container and receive the response. Each of these tools has different capabilities and will require different commands to make the request.

For example, if you want to use cURL, you can issue the following command from the container:

curl -X GET https://example.com

Comment: I am getting result for a lot of websites